# AWStats cron job 'awstats.pl' takes more than 24 hours

Tags: logging, cron, awstats

We have trouble on the AWStats background job reading the `access.log` file: the `awstats.pl` scripts takes **more than 24 hours** and it seems never ends.

We have a web site which has more than 8 million page views per day, generating a `2 GB` Apache `access.log` file every day.

Here is the command log when we tried to run the `awstats.pl` scripts manually:

```
root@hostname:~# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=org.mysite -update

Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.org.mysite" by AWStats version 7.4 (build 20150714)
From data in log file "/var/log/apache2/org.mysite-access.log"...

Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
Direct access to last remembered record is out of file.
So searching it from beginning of log file...

Phase 2 : Now process new records (Flush history on disk after 20000 hosts)...
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
Flush history file on disk (unique url reach flush limit of 5000)
^C
```

We Use `ctrl+C` to stop here, since it has been taken more than 1 hour.

We have tried to Disable the DNS lookup (set as `0`), well it did not help:

Edit the file `/etc/awstats/awstats.org.mysite.conf`

```
 # 0 - No DNS Lookup
 # 1 - DNS Lookup is fully enabled
 # 2 - DNS Lookup is made only from static DNS cache file (if it exists)
 # Default: 2
 DNSLookup=0
```

The hardware should not the bottleneck, it is the ovh.com [HOST-128L](https://www.ovh.com/us/dedicated-servers/hosting/173host3.xml) dedicated server

- Intel  Xeon D-1520 - 4 core / 8 thread
- 128GB DDR4 ECC 2133 MHz
- 2 x 480 GB / SSD

The operation system is **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**

```
root@hostname:~# cat /etc/*-release

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
```

So,

1. Do we have anything to do to improve the AWStats performance?
2. Or are we hitting the performance threshold of AWStats?

Comment: My guess is that you are reaching the performance limit. I don't know if AWStats can handle partial log files. If it can, then you can run AWStats several times a day to process the log bit by bit.